# I need to replace a range of elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have an `std::vector` of certain size, and need to assign the contents of another vector (of size 34) to position 34 ... 67. The size of the original vector should not change. Looking at vector's [API](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

- [assign()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/) doesn't work as it replaces all the elements.
- [swap()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/) doesn't work, since it replaces all the elements.
- [emplace()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace/) doesn't work, as it creates a new element.
- [reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/), followed by a loop of [at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) would work, but it would be nice to avoid the loop.
- memcpy(target.data[34], source.data(), 34 * sizeof(T)) would work without a loop, but looks like a C hack.
- [std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) would work nicely, but hiding away the loop I expect it to be slower than memcpy().

The elements are integral numbers. Which should be the default approach, when changing a range of elements in a vector?

Comment: `std::copy` is the right approach. I bet it's easily fast enough for whatever you need it for. :)

Comment: `std::copy` is the correct approach indeed. For a container of something like POD types and *especially* for native scalars like your integrals I would not be at-all shocked if it specialized to a fundamental `memcpy` intrinsic regardless. *try it*.

Comment: Out of curiousity why do you expect it to be slow?

Comment: @remyabel, I expect it to do a for loop, using `at()` or `[]` individual operations.

Comment: @Vorac: It can't do either, as it only has iterators. Those define `operator*` and `operator++`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::copy` is a good approach for replacing values in a limited range of a vector.

Do not consider `memcpy` at all, since it's UB for non-POD items.

Algorithms like `std::copy` are generally optimized, possibly special-cased for binary copyable types. That is, they do the Right Thing™ automatically. If you are in doubt of the performance, **MEASURE**.

Answer (score 1):

If your types are trivial then use `std::copy` it might be optimized to a `memcopy`.

Else if the vector you are inserting is destroyed after the inserting *and* it is complex, you could try `std::swap_ranges`, saving a call to destroy for a move.

And as Alf already pointed out measure is a good thing.

Comment: It's not a bottleneck I am trying to eliminate. Rather, I am persuing code quality. I don't want to use a stupid way, and after the 400th use in the codebase, to someone notice that performance is going down for some reason.